# Custom markup in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

I want to set my custom markup in my website which is based on Next.js 13. so if users share my website on WhatsApp and other social media, it becomes visible. I tried various methods but did not get desired output.
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

layout.js:

```
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Kandle | Making crypto fun again" />
  <meta
    property="og:description"
    content="We are Kandle. Play fantasy crypto win daily rewards"
  />
  <meta
    property="og:image"
    content="http://kandle.xyz/images/kandle_homepage_og.png"
  />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://kandle.xyz" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="700" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="467" />
```

My Output:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You need a lot more then just some `og:` metatags, those are mainly used by Facebook. See the example at [web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/html/metadata/), they have a full blown snippet near the bottom of the page. You'll also need a [manifest](https://web.dev/add-manifest/) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you include the 'itemprop' attribute in the 'og:image' meta tag. Additionally, ensure that the image size is set to 256x256 pixels. It wouldn't hurt to add the 'site_name,' 'type,' and 'updated_time' properties as well.